# Query 100x slower in SQL Server 2014, Row Count Spool row estimate the culprit?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, cardinality-estimates, query-performance

I have a query that runs in **800 milliseconds in SQL Server 2012** and takes about **170 seconds in SQL Server 2014**. I think that I've narrowed this down to a poor cardinality estimate for the `Row Count Spool` operator. I've read a bit about spool operators (e.g., [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2013/06/11/spooling-in-sql-execution-plans.aspx) and [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/showplan-operator-of-the-week---row-count-spool/)), but am still having trouble understanding a few things:

- Why does this query need a `Row Count Spool` operator? I don't think it's necessary for correctness, so what specific optimization is it trying to provide?
- Why does SQL Server estimate that the join to the `Row Count Spool` operator removes all rows?
- Is this a bug in SQL Server 2014? If so, I'll file in Connect. But I'd like a deeper understanding first.

Note: I can re-write the query as a `LEFT JOIN` or add indexes to the tables in order to achieve acceptable performance in both SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2014. So this question is more about understanding this specific query and plan in depth and less about how to phrase the query differently.

**The slow query**

See [this Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cEDPMh8R) for a full test script. Here is the specific test query I'm looking at:

```
-- Prune any existing customers from the set of potential new customers
-- This query is much slower than expected in SQL Server 2014 
SELECT *
FROM #potentialNewCustomers -- 10K rows
WHERE cust_nbr NOT IN (
    SELECT cust_nbr
    FROM #existingCustomers -- 1MM rows
)
```

**SQL Server 2014: The estimated query plan**

SQL Server believes that the `Left Anti Semi Join` to the `Row Count Spool` will filter the 10,000 rows down to 1 row. For this reason, it selects a `LOOP JOIN` for the subsequent join to `#existingCustomers`.

[image]

**SQL Server 2014: The actual query plan**

As expected (by everyone but SQL Server!), the `Row Count Spool` did not remove any rows. So we are looping 10,000 times when SQL Server expected to loop just once.

[image]

**SQL Server 2012: The estimated query plan**

When using SQL Server 2012 (or `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 9481)` in SQL Server 2014), the `Row Count Spool` does not reduce the estimated # of rows and a hash join is chosen, resulting in a far better plan.

[image]

**The LEFT JOIN re-write**

For reference, here is a way that I may re-write the query in order to achieve good performance in all SQL Server 2012, 2014, and 2016. However, I'm still interested in the specific behavior of the query above and whether it is a bug in the new SQL Server 2014 Cardinality Estimator.

```
-- Re-writing with LEFT JOIN yields much better performance in 2012/2014/2016
SELECT n.*
FROM #potentialNewCustomers n
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS test, cust_nbr FROM #existingCustomers) c
    ON c.cust_nbr = n.cust_nbr
WHERE c.test IS NULL
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why does this query need a Row Count Spool operator? ... what specific optimization is it trying to provide?

The `cust_nbr` column in `#existingCustomers` is nullable. If it actually contains any nulls the correct response here is to return zero rows (`NOT IN (NULL,...)`  will always yield an empty result set.).

So the query can be thought of as

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   #potentialNewCustomers p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   #existingCustomers e1
                   WHERE  p.cust_nbr = e1.cust_nbr)
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM   #existingCustomers e2
                       WHERE  e2.cust_nbr IS NULL)
```

With the rowcount spool there to avoid having to evaluate the

```
EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM   #existingCustomers e2
        WHERE  e2.cust_nbr IS NULL)
```

More than once.

This just seems to be a case where a small difference in assumptions can make quite a catastrophic difference in performance.

After updating a single row as below...

```
UPDATE #existingCustomers
SET    cust_nbr = NULL
WHERE  cust_nbr = 1;
```

... the query completed in less than a second. The row counts in actual and estimated versions of the plan are now nearly spot on.

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
SET STATISTICS IO ON;

SELECT *
FROM   #potentialNewCustomers
WHERE  cust_nbr NOT IN (SELECT cust_nbr
                        FROM   #existingCustomers 
                       )
```

[image]

Zero rows are output as described above.

The Statistics Histograms and auto update thresholds in SQL Server are not granular enough to detect this kind of single row change. Arguably if the column is nullable it might be reasonable to work on the basis that it contains at least one `NULL` even if the statistics histogram doesn't currently indicate that there are any.

Answer (score 9):

> Why does this query need a Row Count Spool operator? I don't think it's necessary for correctness, so what specific optimization is it trying to provide?

See [Martin's thorough answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117468/11635) for this question. The key point is that if a single row within the `NOT IN` is `NULL`, the boolean logic works out such that "the correct response is to return zero rows". The `Row Count Spool` operator is optimizing this (necessary) logic.

> Why does SQL Server estimate that the join to the Row Count Spool operator removes all rows?

Microsoft provides an [excellent white paper on the SQL 2014 Cardinality Estimator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn673537.aspx). In this document, I found the following information:

***The new CE assumes that the queried values do exist in the dataset even if the value falls out of the range of the histogram. The new CE in this example uses an average frequency that is calculated by multiplying the table cardinality by the density.***

Often, such a change is a very good one; it greatly alleviates the [ascending key problem](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2013/02/statistics-on-ascending-keys/) and typically yields a more conservative query plan (higher row estimate) for values that are out-of-range based on the statistics histogram.

However, in this specific case, assuming that a `NULL` value will be found leads to the assumption that joining to the `Row Count Spool` will filter out all rows from `#potentialNewCustomers`. In the case where there in fact is a `NULL` row, this is a correct estimate (as seen in Martin's answer). However, in the case where there happens not to be a `NULL` row, the effect can be devastating because SQL Server produces a post-join estimate of 1 row regardless of how many input rows appear. This can lead to very poor join choices in the remainder of the query plan.

> Is this a bug in SQL 2014? If so, I'll file in Connect. But I'd like a deeper understanding first.

I think it's in the grey area between a bug and a performance-impacting assumption or limitation of SQL Server's new Cardinality Estimator. However, this quirk can cause substantial regressions in performance relative to SQL 2012 in the specific case of a nullable `NOT IN` clause that doesn't happen to have any `NULL` values.

Therefore, I have filed [a Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1897806/) so that the SQL team is aware of the potential implications of this change to the Cardinality Estimator.

**Update:** We're on CTP3 now for SQL16, and I confirmed that the problem does not occur there.

Answer (score 5):

Martin Smith's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117468) and your [self-answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/117899) have addressed all the main points correctly, I just want to emphasise an area for future readers:

> So this question is more about understanding this specific query and plan in depth and less about how to phrase the query differently.

The stated purpose of the query is:

> ```
> -- Prune any existing customers from the set of potential new customers
> ```

This requirement is easy to express in SQL, in several ways. Which one is chosen is as much a matter of style as anything else, but the query specification should still be written to return correct results in all cases. **This includes accounting for nulls.**

Expressing the logical requirement fully:

- Return potential customers who are not already customers
- List each potential customer at most once
- Exclude null potential and existing customers (whatever a null customer means)

We can then write a query matching those requirements using whichever syntax we prefer. For example:

```
WITH DistinctPotentialNonNullCustomers AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        PNC.cust_nbr 
    FROM #potentialNewCustomers AS PNC
    WHERE 
        PNC.cust_nbr IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    DPNNC.cust_nbr
FROM DistinctPotentialNonNullCustomers AS DPNNC
WHERE
    DPNNC.cust_nbr NOT IN
    (
        SELECT 
            EC.cust_nbr 
        FROM #existingCustomers AS EC 
        WHERE 
            EC.cust_nbr IS NOT NULL
    );
```

This produces an efficient execution plan, which returns correct results:

[image: Execution plan]

We can express the `NOT IN` as `<> ALL` or `NOT = ANY` without affecting the plan or results:

```
WITH DistinctPotentialNonNullCustomers AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        PNC.cust_nbr 
    FROM #potentialNewCustomers AS PNC
    WHERE 
        PNC.cust_nbr IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    DPNNC.cust_nbr
FROM DistinctPotentialNonNullCustomers AS DPNNC
WHERE
    DPNNC.cust_nbr <> ALL
    (
        SELECT 
            EC.cust_nbr 
        FROM #existingCustomers AS EC 
        WHERE 
            EC.cust_nbr IS NOT NULL
    );
```

```
WITH DistinctPotentialNonNullCustomers AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        PNC.cust_nbr 
    FROM #potentialNewCustomers AS PNC
    WHERE 
        PNC.cust_nbr IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    DPNNC.cust_nbr
FROM DistinctPotentialNonNullCustomers AS DPNNC
WHERE
    NOT DPNNC.cust_nbr = ANY
    (
        SELECT 
            EC.cust_nbr 
        FROM #existingCustomers AS EC 
        WHERE 
            EC.cust_nbr IS NOT NULL
    );
```

Or using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WITH DistinctPotentialNonNullCustomers AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        PNC.cust_nbr 
    FROM #potentialNewCustomers AS PNC
    WHERE 
        PNC.cust_nbr IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    DPNNC.cust_nbr
FROM DistinctPotentialNonNullCustomers AS DPNNC
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM #existingCustomers AS EC
        WHERE
            EC.cust_nbr = DPNNC.cust_nbr
            AND EC.cust_nbr IS NOT NULL
    );
```

There is nothing magic about this, or anything particularly objectionable about using `IN`, `ANY`, or `ALL` - we just need to write the query correctly, so it will always produce the right results.

The most compact form uses `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT 
    PNC.cust_nbr 
FROM #potentialNewCustomers AS PNC
WHERE 
    PNC.cust_nbr IS NOT NULL
EXCEPT
SELECT
    EC.cust_nbr 
FROM #existingCustomers AS EC
WHERE 
    EC.cust_nbr IS NOT NULL;
```

This produces correct results as well, though the execution plan may be less efficient due to absence of bitmap filtering:

[image: Non-bitmap execution plan]

The original question is interesting because it exposes a performance-affecting problem with the necessary null check implementation. The point of this answer is that writing the query *correctly* avoids the issue as well.